# Hot reload doesn't work on Vue CLI project when using custom host name

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, hot-reload

I have a VueJS 2 project with the following `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'my-project.local'
  }
}
```

When I run `yarn serve` everything works fine. If I make some code changes hot reload works fine at first. But then after about 10 seconds hot reloads stop working.

[image]

If I remove the `devServer` entry form `vue.config.js`, everything works fine again.

Has anyone else experienced this and been able to find a solution?

Comment: Hi Sel, I am currently facing similar issue. Did you find any workaround for it?